# Sort Arraylist in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to sort an ArrayList in my Android app, but its throwing an exception.  Here's the part of my code where it happens:

```
List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);  
Collections.sort(packs);
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What kind of error? Post your logcat

Comment: Show us the error or exception you're getting.

Comment: Have you try to use in-built sort function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

packs contains PackageInfo objects, and sort can not find a natural order for those is my best guess. If you want to sort, use a [Comparator](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Comparator.html) with the sort which defines what you want to sort the PackageInfo objects on.

Answer (score 2):

here is a simple example of **How to sort array in android?**.

```
String[] array = new String[]{"one","two","three","four"};
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

[sorting](http://tutiez.com/?p=57) 
[another example](http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/blog/java-sort-arraylist)
 [one more](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/272.html)
 [this also](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)
may above link helpful to you Happy Coding..:):)
thanks Pragna